# Unexpected aether terrain

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-aether

This is the first time I have downloaded the Aether II launcher. When I created a new world, and went through the portal, the terrain was different than what I have seen on pictures and videos on the web.

Some pictures found on the internet:
[image: aether_img1]
<sub>(source: [9minecraftmods.com](https://www.9minecraftmods.com/p/wp-content/uploads/Aether-2-Mod-8.jpg))</sub>

[image: aether_img2]
[image: aether_img3]
So beautiful!

And this is what I it looks like for me:[image: aether_img4]
So boring!

I checked two different seeds, same result. How can I get that beautiful terrain?

Version: Aether II 1.10.2 public indev

**Edit:**
The only information I have found about it is in [this facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/AetherMod/photos/a.216761868403940.52790.172320626181398/439682342778557/?type=3&theater).
So my question is: if it is optional, how can I turn it off?

Comment: Are those screenshots from the same modversion?

Comment: They are for Aether II, but don't know about the exact version

Comment: Your current version also has the name "indev" which seems to be an indication of "in development", so the new worldgen was possibly not yet reimplemented in the 1.10 version of the mod. I'm not posting this ans an answer because it is just an assumption. Without any sort of source or research behind it.

Comment: He must be using some texture packs I guess , because of that shadows and very smooth textures.

Answer (score -1):

Well in your case most likely they have been using texture packs with the aether to change the looks so just try to look for a texture pack that works with the aether here is one:

http://www.planetminecraft.com/texture_pack/aether-texture-pack-14-update/

Comment: Texture packs cannot change the terrain itself

Answer (score -1):

If your computer can handle it, I would suggest turning on amplified terrain - that may be what the YouTubers are doing. If that doesn't work, or your computer can't handle it, make sure you have the right version. The people in the photos may even be using an earlier version that made the terrain cooler. Other than that, it could just be chance, and those three seeds that you tried are bad. Hope this helps!